# Java Swing MenuItem On click

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I'm testing response times for User Interfaces, and I need to call a timer function stop() when the menu item is selected. Here's the menu item code:

```
        menuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Stop Timer");
        menu.add(menuItem);
```

And here's the time code (there's more but I don't think it's relevant):

```
public void stop() {
    this.stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.running = false;
}
```

How do I get the button to call the function stop() when it is clicked?

Comment: A `JCheckBoxMenuItem` supports `ActionListener`, `ChangeListener` and others.. Add one of them that is appropriate. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Add a listener to the button as it is explained in [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) and call `stop()` there.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add itemListener : `menuitem.addItemistener()`

   ```
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent it){
       stop();   //call your function 
       }
   ```